# V-USB with ATtiny2313 to communicate with Android

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, usb, serial, android

How would one interface a ATtiny2313 with usb to communicate with a android device? I know it involves using V-USB, but how does the circuitry work? Am I supposed to connect certain pins on the ATtiny2313 to certains parts of a usb head? (How do I connect the ATtiny2313 to a micro USB connection) I would really like for the usb to end up connecting straight to the android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is going to be very difficult for two reasons:

- The ATtiny2313 does not have any usb hardware whatsoever.
- Most (all?) android phones are only made to be USB slave not host

I would recommend getting a bluetooth solution which you can talk to over some simple serial interface on your ATtiny2313. That will then talk to the bluetooth on your android phone which is designed to be a host.

For the bluetooth solution for the microprocessor side I recommend something like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8550), and on the Android phone you can download the app called "Blueterm" which is essentially a terminal that when you type a message and then press enter it sends the message over bluetooth. It also detects the bluetooth slave device (the chip from sparkfun) and connects to it.

**EDIT:** Ok some brief googling tells me I'm wrong about all Androids only being USB slave. It seems some more recent phones coupled with more recent OSes can in fact be USB host. However, it doesn't change my opinion that the bluetooth route would be much simpler.

On VUSB - that is a complex-ish code library that I will not delve into, any questions about that are probably better suited for StackOverflow. The hardware however is not that complicated, USB uses [differential signaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling) for its data lines. Everything you need to know about pull-up and line terminating resistors can be found on this guy's [site](http://codeandlife.com/2012/01/25/avr-attiny-usb-tutorial-part-2/). You also need to make sure you have the right voltage level for an android's usb port.

Comment: I definitely understand what your saying, I would love to go the bluetooth route except im worried about powering the accessory. I would have to add an onboard battery that was rechargeable and thats a whole other deal. I'm willing to deal with the suck involved in usb serial communication. I just would like to know how I would go about using V USB with the ATtiny2313. Namely being how the circuitry and VUSB firmware works. Do you have any insight on that? Bluetooth or USB route? Thanks :D

Comment: My friend. You are a gentleman and a scholar. That tutorial is exactly what I have been looking for. (Funny thing is StackOverflow sent me here, and now I am going to be sent back. I'm in limbo! O.o) Thank you for setting me in the right direction!

Comment: This is not a very good answer; it starts out by rejecting the premise of the question as if the lack of dedicated USB hardware would make the task impossible, and only sneaks the links to how it would be done in later.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I recommended a different way of doing it because I didn't think android phones could be USB host. Once I found out that was false, I edited my answer. You take issue with what part of that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [IOIO](https://github.com/ytai/ioio), because it should take care of, most of your requirements. Also the hardware, is relatively inexpensive, i.e. compared to most other ADK kits.